# Access GHC package database in test and benchmark suite

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack, ghc-pkg

I have a test suite and a benchmark suite that uses the GHC API to compile modules to Core, so that I don't have to write Core ['by hand'](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-8.2.1/docs/MkCore.html).

I'm mostly using `stack` at this point, where I could just access the `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable in the test suite (`stack test`) to find a package database which I can feed the GHC API with. Note that it's not so much that I care for any particular db, I just want to have modules from e.g. `base` available, compiled with a compatible version of GHC (e.g. [`GHC.Paths.ghc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-paths-0.1.0.9/docs/GHC-Paths.html#v:ghc)).

Everything works fine so far, tests are green. Now, if I do the same for the benchmark suite (`stack bench`), `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH` doesn't seem to be present at all.

Long story short, what is a reliable way to capture the path to the GHC package database the program was built with? I imagine some messing about with `Setup.hs` might get me where I want to be.

---

Edit: Here is something to play around with: https://github.com/sgraf812/ghc-package-path

`stack test` prints out the value of `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH`, whereas `stack bench` doesn't. An answer to this question should make it so that a path to some appropriate package database is printed out in either case.

Comment: Thanks for the report, I've opened this issue: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3462

Comment: @mgsloan Thanks for fixing this! Nonetheless, I'm interested in a solution that also works for cabal-install. Looking at the code of ghc-mod, there probably isn't really a solution, I think, but I think this situation is really annoying and there should be some kind of package for this (like `ghc-paths`) if there is no standard among the ecosystem.

Comment: @mgsloan So, what would be the best workaround? I dug through the `stack` source code and looked at how `mkGhcPackagePath` is called. seems like I have to get a hold on an `EnvConfig` to call `packageDatabaseLocal` et al. What would be the easiest way to do so?

Comment: Maybe I'm better off just parsing the result of `stack path --ghc-package-path`?

Comment: Yeah, parsing that seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution appears to be to use a custom `Setup.hs` to persist the [`withPackageDB`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.0.0.2/docs/Distribution-Simple-LocalBuildInfo.html#v:withPackageDB) field of the `LocalBuildInfo` after `configure`.

Lucky me found [`cabal-toolkit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-toolkit), of which I modified version 0.0.3 to also work with Cabal 1.24 (and GHC 8.0.2) [to be found here](https://github.com/sgraf812/cabal-toolkit/commit/5a083bc6f88673a7cd199b152b39d0a799b28773) until it's merged.

Getting the `packageDBFlags`/`extraPkgConf` is just a matter of calling `getGHCPackageFlags $(localBuildInfoQ)`.